# Delete from a Select in mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I'm doing some sql in SQL Fiddle,

I'm trying to do a DELETE from a SELECT.

Normally I first delete the rows, and after I do a SELECT to see if my rows have been succesfully deleted, but now i'm a bit stuck because I want to do that simultaneusly.

This is my SELECT (to select the ID that are not in the table ORDERS):

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers 
WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM orders)
```

and this is my DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM customers
WHERE customer_id IN (1,3,4,9);
```

Now I've tried this

```
DELETE FROM customers
WHERE customer_id IN ( SELECT customer_id
    FROM customers 
    WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM orders)
);
```

but i have this error:

`You can't specify target table 'customers' for update in FROM clause`

Thanks for the help!

This is my fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0c94d

Comment: and why didn't you post the error or the link to the fiddle

Comment: Rewrite your WHERE [NOT] IN to common JOINs, and the task will become trivial. PS. Study multiple-table DELETE syntax.

Comment: *I want to do that simultaneusly* Not exactly sure what you mean by this; a query usually either deletes rows or it returns a resultset (exception such as *sql-server output clause*)

Comment: @Akina i know the erro rmessage, but for a clear question,he should have added it

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to this type of things, I updated my post with the link of the fiddle

Comment: @Akina don't know how to rewrite it with a join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the second custemrs table, and it is clear with every delete the table changes.

You can rewrite your Query by addind a simple subquery for the customers

```
CREATE TABLe customers (customer_id int)
```

```
CREATE tABLE orders(customer_id int)
```

```
DELETE FROM customers
WHERE customer_id IN ( SELECT customer_id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM customers) c 
    WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM orders)
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WppDsuYx)

But simpoler is to avoid it all together as it is not needed

```
CREATE TABLe customers (customer_id int)
```

```
CREATE tABLE orders(customer_id int)
```

```
DELETE FROM customers
WHERE customer_id  NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM orders)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2tOBwY0E)

Comment: Oh thanks, the first solution was good for me but i didn't understand precisely why my solution did not work, can you explain it to me? (Also in chat if it's not a problem for you)

Comment: basically the delete deletes rows by going one by one row, that means that the table customers is constantly changing, so the rdms can't use it in the subquery. but when you make a (SELECT * FROM ..) you actually make a temporary table, before the query is run, so it is a fixed not changing table, which can be used in the subquery which is the same custermans table before the deleting starts.